# Porqué el resultado de varios Inner Joins resultan en un único campo y no una tabla ¿que puedo estar haciendo mal?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo el siguiente código `PostgreSQL`:

```
SELECT(v1.contrato, v1.status, v1.sucursal, p1.numero_pedido, 
        p1.contrato, p1.status, p2.nombre, p2.apellido_pat, p2.apellido_mat, p2.telefono_dire) 
FROM vales as v1 
INNER JOIN pedidos as p1
On v1.contrato=p1.contrato
INNER JOIN personas as p2
on v1.contrato=p2.contrato
INNER JOIN contratos as c1
on v1.contrato=c1.contrato
WHERE v1.sucursal IN (12,22,49,58)
```

el resultado debería ser una tabla, sin embargo me arroja un único registo:

```
"(""1002    "",1,12,184,""1002    "",""1 "",Omar,Chávez,Hernández,5655124545)"
"(""1003    "",1,22,785,""1003    "",""1 "",Ruben,Luján,García,5709385319)"
"(""1004    "",1,49,654,""1004    "",""1 "",Fernanda,Darío,López,5760724862)"
"(""1005    "",0,58,156,""1005    "",""0 "",Lucia,Montés,Hernández,5833087616)"
"(""1006    "",1,58,185,""1006    "",""1 "",María,Fuentes,Flores,5902914550)"
"(""1007    "",1,22,488,""1007    "",""1 "",Edna,López,Garces,5955452979)"
"(""1011    "",0,49,485,""1011    "",""0 "",Luisa,Pérez,""de la O"",6246720900)"
```

¿Qué puedo estar haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya intentaste quitar los ( ) de tu consulta?

Pareciera que esta agrupando todo por los parentesis y por eso solo te regresa una columna.

Comment: Para poder responder con valor a las preguntas tipo a esta, deberías de tener en cuenta lo que indica el enlace. [¿Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo y verificable?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

Comment: Y por cierto: [_no uses firmas, taglines o saludos_](/help/behavior).